# How do I kill a process with the .NET framework?

Tags: c#, .net, process, kill-process

I'm writing an application in C#, and I'd like to close some other application—Internet Explorer, say. I've seen a lot of results for how to close the application *you're* building, but I want close an *external program* and I'm not sure where to start.

What part of the .NET framework would I use to do this?

Comment: If you know the process name, you can kill it, [there's a kill method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx).

Comment: if you are going to down vote it, put in the reason why...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can kill the processes that match a specific name by `using System.Diagnostics.Process;`:

```
foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses())
{
    if (clsProcess.ProcessName.StartsWith("iexplore"))
    {
        clsProcess.Kill();                
    }
}
```